# Why are nvidia binary drivers called opensource in Software & Updates?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, open-source

I was curious looking into various tabs of Software & Updates GUI, and found a strange thing: most of versions of nvidia binary drivers are called "opensource". Only legacy ones are called proprietary. See the screenshot below.

[image: screenshot]

What does this mean? Have NVidia really released their drivers as open source?

This doesn't seem true, see this output:

```
$ dmesg|grep taints
[    1.269797] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
```

Comment: All Nvidia drivers are proprietary. It is a bug. I answered that somewhere already.

Comment: @Pilot6 If there is another question asking the same thing which you've answered already, then please vote to close this one as a duplicate of it.

Comment: If you know how to find it, you can do it as well. ;-)

Comment: I found it ))))